# Colour of image changes when uploading to website

Tags: html, css, image

This might not strictly a coding question. 
I build a website in paraellex theme.

> http://cableandmedia.com/abrademo/

My issue is that the images are not getting their right colours and loose some clarity also.
This is the [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tskLz.png) banner image.

Comment: Those images look identical for me, especially color-wise. It’s just scaled up a bit when used as a background.

Comment: Which Browser do you use. I use Chrome and doesn't see any difference. I also checked the image which is used in the css http://cableandmedia.com/abrademo/images/slant1.png and your provided image http://i.stack.imgur.com/tskLz.png. They are identical to 100 percent. So if you think they are different there has to be a problem with the css depending on your browser

Comment: Firefox: looks fine. Please make screenshot of both images side by side to compare them. Maybe you put some other content and that makes illution of color change?

Comment: Is it possible you have some overlay with a translucent background that covers the window?